# Highcharts, vue component. 3 charts in 1

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

[expected chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PADo.png)

Hi, I need to make this charts, looks like 3 charts in 1(?). I can make the 2 scatered ones, but the column charts its tricky. Thanks to Wojciech Chmiel I was able to make this columns charts with highcharts-vue, but the chart behaviour its a little odd, I cant add a yAxis, nor stop the chart from pushing to the top like a sort of responsive behaviour.

Comment: Could you elaborate on an online demo of what you already have?

Comment: Hi!, I was able to find a useful example https://www.highcharts.com/demo/box-plot. I adapted this to suit my needs. Now I'm only struggling with the colors, I need 2 types of blue interspersed. Thank for your time!

Comment: Hi, I'm glad you've found an example. You need 2 types of blue color, yet for what? Series? Points? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

@Wojciech Chmiel
Hi, sorry for the delay. [A columnrange chart with a bloxplot and 2 scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQQV8.png)

```js
initChart (data) {
      this.chartOptions = merge(this.getBaseChartConfig(ChartTypes.BoxPlot), {
        xAxis: {
          categories: data.periods
        },
        series: [
          {
            type: 'columnrange',
            name: 'Observations',
            data:data.peerGroupStatisticReturns.dataRange,
            showInLegend: false
          },
          {
            type: 'boxplot',
            linkedTo: ':previous',
            data: data.peerGroupStatisticReturns.values
          },
          {
            type: 'scatter',
            name: data.names[1],
            marker: {
              symbol: 'diamond',
              fillColor: '#6598FD',
              radius: 6
            },            
            data: data.benchmarkReturnSeries.data
          },
          {
            type: 'scatter',
            name: data.names[2],
            marker: {
              symbol: 'square',
              fillColor: '#FFCC33'
            },            
            data: data.productReturnSeries.data
          }
        ]
      })
      
      // chart settings
const boxPlotConfig = {
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    boxplot: {
      fillColor: '#0076C0',
      medianColor: '#303030',
      medianWidth: 1,
      stemWidth: 0,
      whiskerWidth: 0,
      color: '#303030',
      showInLegend: false
    },
    columnrange: {
      color: '#66ADD9'
    },
    series: {
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      borderColor: '#303030'
    }
  },
  
  yAxis: {
    title: ''
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Now I have make the colors interspersed and move the markers so the dont overlap, one to the right inside the column and one to the left